# Will a non-unicode application fail to run on some machines internationally?

Tags: c++

And if not, is the benefit of using unicode to display more characters?

Comment: does your application supports UI translations to other languages also?

Comment: The application has no UI. Just a console. It also only prints English characters.

Comment: Are you using Windows, or are you using a platform that supports UTF-8?

Comment: @jamesdlin: Yes, I am using Windows. The program is designed to run on any Windows version after XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on a lot of things.  If your program is simple, you might be able to get away with it, but odds are that there's going to be some API where the presence of Unicode strings is going to trip you up.

The simplest example would be filenames—if there's anywhere in your program where you ask the user to specify a file, he could easily specify a filename containing a Unicode character in its path.  If you only use the ANSI APIs, such as `fopen()` or `CreateFileA()`, then you will not be able to open that file, and the user will be frustrated that your program doesn't work.  So unless you have a really good reason, you should almost always be using the Unicode APIs (e.g. `_wfopen()` or `CreateFileW()` in this case).